# Making a Folder to Auto Open When Running an Application on Windows

Tags: windows-10, boot, public-folders

I post a new question since my last post lacks details.

I am running **Windows 10 Professional** on my PC. I created a **custom windows application** on Visual Studio 2017. I need Windows to open up a certain local folder on my PC (folder located on C: drive) whenever I click on Desktop shortcut to run the application. I'm not sure if I need to do this on my codes or I can just directly create a setting on Windows instead to auto open up the folder.

I found online that a user can make a folder/software to auto open during Windows boot up. Is there any way that I can make a folder to auto open **when I run** my custom application/software on my PC instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no concept of Windows opening a folder, during boot nor at any other time.

What you can do is opening a folder in File Explorer, a part of the Windows UI shell.

You can do that by starting

```
 explorer.exe "C:\Program Files\Windows Defender"
```

this would open a new Windows with the directory you have specified.

If you want to open a folder in File Explorer alongside with your app, create a `cmd` batch file with content similar to this:

```
C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe
explorer.exe "C:\Program Files\Windows Defender"
```

the first line would be your program.

Comment: thank you. This would be a great help for me. However, it would be great if u can guide me more on creating the cmd batch file. Just to clarify, from the batch file I am able to open up a folder whenever I run my program correct?

Comment: I figured this one out. I need to navigate to the correct path first before actually execute the command above. Thank you for your help!